# Blazor on docker containers

Tags: docker, .net-core, blazor

Anyone managed to run a server-side hosted Blazor application on a docker container?

I am getting the following exception when I run it:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {c1fe0008-8b2b-46a3-9f80-233ae59e5d17} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.GenericWebHostService[6]
      Application startup exception
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not load the embedded file manifest 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded.Manifest.xml' for assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded.Manifest.ManifestParser.Parse(Assembly assembly, String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider..ctor(Assembly assembly)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ConfigureStaticFilesOptions.PostConfigure(String name, StaticFileOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware..ctor(RequestDelegate next, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnv, IOptions`1 options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<UseMiddleware>b__0(RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Internal.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not load the embedded file manifest 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded.Manifest.xml' for assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded.Manifest.ManifestParser.Parse(Assembly assembly, String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider..ctor(Assembly assembly)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ConfigureStaticFilesOptions.PostConfigure(String name, StaticFileOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware..ctor(RequestDelegate next, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnv, IOptions`1 options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<UseMiddleware>b__0(RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Internal.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at BlazorUI.ServerSided.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/BlazorUI.ServerSided/Program.cs:line 19
```

**EDIT:** This is a clean project, added by Visual Studio when creating new ASP.Net Core Web Application > Blazor (server-side). No other changes were made to the project.

Dockerfile was created by selecting the project (right-click) > add > docker support:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["BlazorUI.ServerSided/BlazorUI.ServerSided.csproj", "BlazorUI.ServerSided/"]
RUN dotnet restore "BlazorUI.ServerSided/BlazorUI.ServerSided.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/BlazorUI.ServerSided"
RUN dotnet build "BlazorUI.ServerSided.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "BlazorUI.ServerSided.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BlazorUI.ServerSided.dll"]
```

I am using .net-core 3-preview4-011223 and linux containers.

The image is published [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/mihaimyh/blazoruiserversided).

Comment: Would you please consider editing your question to provide more details? Which version of blazor are you using? Which docker images are you using? Have you made any changes to the scaffolded code (created when you call `dotnet new`)? Also, please wrap your stack trace in triple back tics to allow for multi-line formatting.

Comment: Hi @JamieTaylor, thank you for your suggestion, I added requested information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hitting well known issue in Preview 4 release which affect Linux build
See https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9402
Asp.NET Team claim to fix that in Preview 5

To solve your issue, you should use daily build of Preview 5 as of 5 May 2019.

You can get builds of Preview5 from https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/docs/DailyBuilds.md

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found out so far and it is working for now (with https and subdomain):

Setup subdomain in Startup.cs -> Configure:

```
        string basePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_BASEPATH");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(basePath))
        {
            app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                context.Request.Scheme = "https";
                return next();
            });

            app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                context.Request.PathBase = new PathString(basePath);
                if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(basePath, out var remainder))
                {
                    context.Request.Path = remainder;
                }
                return next();
            });
        }
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
```

Apache config for example subdomain ‘helloapp’ and docker port 9124 [aspnetcore-3.0#configure-apache](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-3.0#configure-apache)

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}helloapp-error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}helloapp-access.log common

  UseCanonicalName On
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
  SSLCipherSuite HIGH

  SSLProxyEngine On
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  ProxyRequests Off
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket
  RewriteRule /helloapp/(.*) wss://localhost:9124/$1 [P,QSA,L]

  <Location /helloapp >
    LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
    LoadModule proxy_http_module    modules/mod_proxy_http.so
    LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass https://127.0.0.1:9124
    ProxyPassReverse https://127.0.0.1:9124
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Assuming you have a letsencrypt SSLCertificate you have to convert it so Kestrel can use it. On your Linux Server run in a terminal the following command. The path to the privkey, cert and chain file can be found in your apache config. This will create a certificate.pfx – you have to enter a valid password for Kestrel.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privkey.pem -in cert.pem -certfile chain.pem
```

Get the Dockerfile from [hub.docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-sdk/) e.g. [bionic/amd64/Dockerfile](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/3.0/sdk/bionic/amd64/Dockerfile)
Add this line at the bottom of the Dockerfile:

```
COPY ./certificate.pfx /root/certificate.pfx
```

Copy the certificate.pfx file and the Dockerfile to an empty folder. Create a file docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  helloapp:
    build: .
    #restart: always
    ports:
      - "9123:80"
      - "9124:443"
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_BASEPATH: /helloapp
      ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT: 9124
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: "https://+:443;http://+:80"
      Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path: /root/certificate.pfx
      Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password: mycertificatesecret
    volumes:
      - ./helloapp:/helloapp
    working_dir: /helloapp
    command: ["dotnet", "helloapp.dll"]
```

Create a subfolder helloapp and copy your published WebApp to it.

Then you can start the container and it should be availabe in www.example.com/helloapp

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```